# App Engine Bulk Loader Download Data Corrupt File

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cmd

I am using Google App Engine and I have a high replication datastore on my current web application. I am attempting to test AE's bulkloader to download a 'kind' from my datastore. I am entering the following code in my CMD in order to download all entities of the inputted 'kind.'

```
python appcfg.py download_data --kind=TestClass --url=http://bulkloader-testing.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=success.csv
```

> The download seems to occur successfully:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Jack Frost>cd..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd "Program Files (x86)"

C:\Program Files (x86)>cd "Google App Engine SDK"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google App Engine SDK>python appcfg.py download_data  --kind=TestClass --url=http://bulkloader-testing.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=success.csv
Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20120125.155035
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20120125.155035.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20120125.155035.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to bulkloader-testing.appspot.com/remote_api
[INFO    ] Downloading kinds: ['TestClass']
.[INFO    ] TestClass: No descending index on __key__, performing serial download
.
[INFO    ] Have 14 entities, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 14 entities (4808 bytes) transferred in 2.3 seconds
```

> However; when I open the .csv file on my computer it opens and is un-comprehensible (I have opened it both with excel and notepad...Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? Below is what the output looks like:
>
> SQLite format 3   @
>   ü Õ fÏÕ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   GGtablebulkloader_database_signaturebulkloader_database_signatureCREATE TABLE bulkloader_database_signature (
>         value TEXT not null)g)tableresultresultCREATE TABLE result (
>   id BLOB primary key,
>   value BLOB not null,
>   sort_key BLOB)+? indexsqlite_autoindex_result_1result      ö    ûö „                                                                                                                  ML‚\
>   :TestClass  00000000000000001003j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassërid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassëŠ!
>   GAEGamer@gmail.com  gmail.com  )L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000001002j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassêrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassê)L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000001001j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassérid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassé'L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000000002j'js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClass'L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000000001j'js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  Te

ú Û¶‘lG"ýØ³ŽiDú                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      $L:TestClass  00000000000000006001$L:TestClass  00000000000000005001
$L:TestClass  00000000000000004001$L:TestClass  00000000000000003003$L:TestClass  00000000000000003002
$L:TestClass  00000000000000003001  $L:TestClass  00000000000000002003$L:TestClass  00000000000000002002$L:TestClass  00000000000000002001$L:TestClass  00000000000000001003$L:TestClass  00000000000000001002$L:TestClass  00000000000000001001$L:TestClass  00000000000000000002$L:TestClass  00000000000000000001
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {ƒ}
  app_id: s~bulkloader-testing
  url: http://bulkloader-testing.appspot.com/remote_api
  kind: TestClass
  download: False
  map: False
  dump: True
  restore: False
  progress_db: bulkloader-progress-20120125.155035.sql3
  has_header: False

> „ V¬ T „                                                                                                                  ML‚\
>   :TestClass  00000000000000001003j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassërid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassëŠ!
>   GAEGamer@gmail.com  gmail.com  )L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000001002j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassêrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassê)L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000001001j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassérid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassé'L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000000002j'js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClass'L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000000001j'js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClass
>       ¤ T¨üP ¤                                                                                                                                                  )
>   L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000003002j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassºrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassº) L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000003001j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClass¹rid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClass¹)L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000002003j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassÓrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassÓ)L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000002002j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassÒrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassÒ)L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000002001j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassÑrid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassÑ
>      P T¨üP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                )L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000006001j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClassñ.rid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClassñ.)
>   L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000005001j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClass‰'rid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClass‰')L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000004001j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClass¡rid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClass¡)L‚
>   :TestClass  00000000000000003003j(js~bulkloader-testingr    TestClass»rid  *Ò…ØÌrmobile  *
>   9786978770rname  *Bulkloader Test‚  TestClass»
>
> UPDATE: I assume the reason is because this is an SQLLite format and hence may not be a true CSV. I will check tomorrow when I come into work and update again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bulk downloader is downloading to SQLite, not CSV.  If you want CSV you have to create and configure bulkloader.yaml: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Editing_the_Configuration_File

Specifying csv in the filename is not enough.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and got it to work but it only allows me to download one "kind" at a time.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pain in a lot of ways.  I tried desperately to get it to output xml for my Java app for at least a few hours with no luck.  I see "bulk export" on the appengine roadmap though, so maybe they have some relief planned for us :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I still do not know why when I view the .csv file it has unintelligible symbols in it BUT I have verified that the contents of the file are what they should be. After downloading the .csv file via the bulkloader I flushed the datastore and then re-uploaded the .csv file. After re-uploading the .csv file all of the datastore's prior content was restored. As a result, I assume the unintelligible symbols are due to my computer lacking some sort of configuration/software but since I only need the data itself and not a visual display of it I am moving on :)

Comment: The filename ends in .csv, but it is in an entirely different format.  This is not a lack of software on your computer.

Comment: Yeah, more fiddling around with it lead me the same answer. Thanks :)